# Objective-C equivalent of UnsafePointer<CChar>

Tags: objective-c, swift

I try to write on Objective-C the Swift codes written on [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial).

I almost written all of it to Objective-C except for this part:

`let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)`

My question is how can I write that part from Swift to Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Objective-C is a superset of C so you can look here to find out the answer:

[Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

```
C Syntax          | Swift Syntax
------------------+----------------------------
char, signed char | CChar
const Type *      | UnsafePointer<Type>
```

So a Swift `UnsafePointer<CChar>` is a Objective-C `const char *`

Comment: from the link you've given, its `const char*` not `const CChar *`, but I will accept your answer, Thanks for the link, BTW!

Comment: You're right, I didn't look past the pointer part. I'll update my answer. Thanks!